# Extract text from custom <h2> in <div> elements by BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hi i try to extract the name from h2 but an error occurs and names are extracted from other `<h2>` I want to extract names from `<h2>` specified from only `<div class="poap serp-container lawyer"><div class="gray_border"><div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-8 text_container"><h2 class=""indigo_text>Hi My name is Mark</h2></div></div></div>`

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import zip_longest
name = []
page_num = 1
phone = []
logo = []
website = []
links = []
while True:
    try:
        result = requests.get(f"https://attorneys.superlawyers.com/motor-vehicle-accidents/texas/houston/page{page_num}/")
        src = result.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
        page_limit = int("126")
        if(page_num > page_limit // 20):
            print("page ended, terminate")
            break
        names = soup.find_all("h2", {"class":"indigo_text"})
        for i in range(len(names)) :
            name.append(names[i].text.strip())
            links.append(names[i].find("a").attrs["href"])
        for link in links:
            result = requests.get(link)
            src = result.content
            soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
            phones = soup.find("a", {"class":"profile-phone-header profile-contact-btn"})
            phone.append(phones["href"])
            logos = soup.find("div", {"class":"photo-container"})
            logo.append(logos.find('img')['src'])
            websites = soup.find("a", {"class":"profile-website-header","id":"firm_website"})
            website.append(websites.text.strip())
        page_num +=1
        print("page switched")
    except:
        print("error")
        break
file_list = [name, phone, website, logo]
exported = zip_longest(*file_list)
with open("/Users/dsoky/Desktop/fonts/Moaaz.csv", "w") as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    wr.writerow(["name","phone","website","logo"])
    wr.writerows(exported)
```

I hope you guys can help me solve this problem

Comment: "*an error occurs*" Why haven't you included the full stack trace of the error you're referencing (along with all other pertinent debugging information) per [ask]?

Comment: sorry because it is secret information i need just how to extract specific <h2> tag in multiple <div>

Comment: I will edit it now

Comment: can you provide a stacktrace? or a minimum reproducible example to test your code with?

Comment: i want to extract names just in <h2> in the specific <div> i try to test the code But it extracts another <h2> that I don't want

Comment: @esqew I modified the question and I hope you can help me how to extract the names of people in <h2> within <div class="poap serp-container lawyer"> only

Comment: "*it is secret information*" A stack trace is "*secret information*"...? Can you share *why* that is, or why it's not reproducible with less sensitive data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your tag more specific for example with following `css selector`:

```
names = soup.select('div.poap h2')
```

or with all the classes:

```
names = soup.select('div.poap.serp-container.lawyer h2.indigo_text')
```

**Note** *This answer just focus to main point in question, code could be imporved to avoid some side effects.*

Comment: It really worked, but there is a problem. Names were extracted multiple times
https://prnt.sc/26kl0w0

Comment: That is caused by the way your code works - Not focus of the question, but predestined elaborate by yourself or to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with focus on this special issue. (Hint: avoid these bunch of lists, work with one list of dicts to get better structure).

Comment: I posted a new question about the problem that occurred if you can you can modify the structure of the code

Comment: Could you help me to improve the code  to avoid some side effects i posted another question